# Selenium - Web Driver Wait

Tags: java, selenium

Here is what I normally write for finding an element with name =" email "

```
WebElement emailInput = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
                .name("email")));
```

What if there is an element modal body as seen below

```
WebElement modalBody = enrollForm.findElement(By
        .className("modal-body"));
```

Now, if I was to find a specific WebElement within another WebElement sorta like...

```
WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.id("KeepSmiling");
WebElement b = a.findElement(By.className("ChocolatesMakeMeSizzle");
```

Here `b` is an element within `a`. Since there are many other div with className -> ChocolatesMakeMeSizzle

I wish to do the same but with `WebDriverWait`. I avoid this issue using `Thread.sleep(xx)` but its a really bad method.

Here is what I tried (but I realized that Im trying to slow down a webElement which makes no sense).

```
WebElement emailInput = (new WebDriverWait(modalBody, 10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
                .name("email")));
```

Any tips how to achieve this?

Confessions: I honestly was avoiding this method and using Thread.sleep(xx).

I am able to use the xpath and find the way but I am hoping for an answer to my question! :)

Comment: We could help with an xpath with some html from your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WebElement emailInput = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
       .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
            .xpath("some_complex_xpath")));
```

If the element is present on the DOM, you should not have a problem with the Modal.
I'm testing a big system and all the forms are modal, we dont have any problem to find the element using ExpectedConditions.

Also, for finding you can use XPATH...

here's a example: 
//input[contains(@class, 'name')]/following::input[@type='Button']

Comment: Thanks for that. I probably will use xpath if ids dont work. I am not so good w/ xpaths to be very honest. I can definitely find it eventually but I was hoping to use modalBody...somehow...id's and className makes me feel in a secure bubble.

Comment: Could you please post the HTML of that modal? In xpath you can use some functions like contains, text(), and navigate functions like /following, etc. It helps a lot! :)

Comment: No worries any more, I sat through it and figured it out! :D

Comment: Although, I really wish I could use it the way I want :(